# How to join a chain of promises into a single promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, fetch-api

I want to return a chain of Promises into a single Promise. I want to know how acheive it.

```
function xbox(){
    let games = "https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=f648fbbe7d024a9d9b021bbd24cea8b5"
    let pages = []
    let videogames = []
    let play
    for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        let response = fetch(games + `&page=${i}`)
        pages.push(response)
        let game = response.then(res => res.json()).then(data => data.results.map((e) => {
            let allgames = {
                ID: e.id
            }
            return allgames
        }))
        videogames = videogames.concat(game)
        play = Promise.all(videogames.flat(1))
    }
    return play
}
```

Output

[image]

Basically my desired output would be a single Promise instead of showing a chain of 5 Promises with 20 results, a single Promise with 100 results.

I appreciate any help with my inquiry!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `async/await`?

Comment: I'm console login in the developer tool of Chrome. Just for curiosity :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flatten the result *after* calling `Promise.all` on the array of promises.

```
return play
  .then(results => results.flat());
```

```js
function xbox(){
    let games = "https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=f648fbbe7d024a9d9b021bbd24cea8b5"
    let pages = []
    let videogames = []
    let play
    for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        let response = fetch(games + `&page=${i}`)
        pages.push(response)
        let game = response.then(res => res.json()).then(data => data.results.map((e) => {
            let allgames = {
                ID: e.id
            }
            return allgames
        }))
        videogames = videogames.concat(game)
        play = Promise.all(videogames.flat(1))
    }
    return play
      .then(results => results.flat());
}
xbox().then(console.log);
```

Cleaning your code up some more, it can be made to look like:

```js
function xbox(){
    const baseUrl = "https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=f648fbbe7d024a9d9b021bbd24cea8b5";
    return Promise.all(Array.from(
        { length: 5 },
        (_, i) => fetch(baseUrl + '&page=' + (i + 1))
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => data.results.map(({ id }) => ({ ID: id })))
    ))
      .then(results => results.flat());
}
xbox().then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use promise all and club all the promises into single.

Issue with your code is you're trying to loop and in each iteration you're trying to put promise as Promise.all which doesn't makes sense as in each iteration you're getting one promise only.

So you need to loop and collect all promises and then place it in Promise.all

```js
function xbox() {
  let games = "https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=f648fbbe7d024a9d9b021bbd24cea8b5"
  return Promise.all(Array.from({
    length: 5
  }, (a, i) => i + 1).map(v => {
    return fetch(games + `&page=${v}`).then(res => res.json()).then(data => data.results.map((e) => {
      let allgames = {
        ID: e.id
      }
      return allgames
    }))
  }))
}

xbox().then(d => console.log(d.flat(1)))
```